# Unable to get class information for checkstyle

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have Java code that works properly. But when I checked it with checkstyle it shows some Issue like "Unable to get class information when I imported the package "import org.json.JSONException;".How do I solve this Issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate this issue by setting the 'suppressLoadErrors' property in the 'RedundantThrows' module of your checkstyle.xml file in the following way:

```
<module name="RedundantThrows">
    <property name="suppressLoadErrors" value="true"/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `RedundantThrows` has now been removed, but I saw the same problem with `JavadocMethod`.  Adding `suppressLoadErrors` worked for me too:

```
<module name="JavadocMethod">
    <property name="scope" value="public"/>
    <property name="suppressLoadErrors" value="true"/>
</module>
```

Comment: This appears to be a regression in Gradle 6.12: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/855